# Want to test my mapreduce by only operating on a couple of entities

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I'm ready to rock and roll with my little mapreduce routine (Python, Google Appengine), but I'm nervous about having some bug that will infect my database table.  My processing function looks like this:

```
def promote(nrhp_aux_entity):
      ...
      # I form a query, and use it to get an "nrhp_record". That's the item
      # I'm actually changing
      results1 = query1.fetch(limit=1)
      nrhp_record = results1[0]
      ...
      yield op.db.Put(np_record)
```

I'd like to have it run on just a small number of nrhp_aux_entity objects, and then just exit. Then I can look over the results and decide to let it work on the whole table. So would a good plan be to have a global counter of some sort, and then exit the whole mapreduce, when say, the counter gets to some small number, like 5? And if so, what's a good way to implement the global counter?

And if I do this, I expect my mapreduce will be all finished in just a minute or so, right, since it only is operating on 5 entities in my database table, (which contains about 76,000 entities)?

Comment: Is there any way you can avoid doing a query in every mapper call, such as by mapping over the type you're querying on instead, or at least using a get instead? That's going to be a lot slower than a regular mapreduce, and cost more too. Also, note that `query1.get()` will return the first result, or None if there is no result - much easier than `query1.fetch(limit=1)[0]`.

Comment: Right now, I'm using the remote_api, because I'm more secure with that. But thanks for the tip about query1.get().  The situation is that I have two tables.   Table B has a handful of extra fields that I really wish had been in Table A all along. There are less items in table B, but for every row in table B, there is one and only one row in table A that I'd like to "promote" all the fields in that row to. So I am iterating over each row in table B, and promoting all it's fields to table A. Table A and table B share a field called "refnum", so it is easy to match them up.

Comment: Are you using key names anywhere? Can you do a simple datastore lookup instead of a query?

Comment: Time for me to go into student mode, and learn more about this. Both tables have a "primary key" named refnum, but in terms of my code, I think it's just another field, not privileged in any way,  I think I probably should be leveraging this field in a better way.

Comment: My follow up question is. Can I create a key name, after the fact, after I already have a table of say, 76 thousand entries? And I'm fairly certain there are no duplicate "refnum" columns, but if there were, would I introduce some corruption into my database table by trying to specify "refnum" as the key name?

Comment: A key name forms part of the key, which uniquely identifies an entity. You can't change a key name, because that's functionally equivalent to creating a new entity with a new key name - which is what you have to do if you want to start using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would copy a few entities to a new kind and set the mapper going on that new kind. Implementing a counter that works at high contention is harder than just making a separate test environment, and the test environment has the benefit of not working on any real data.

Google also just released useful backup / restore features you might want to use before setting your mapper loose on all of your production data!

Depending on your queue settings and how long a single mapping task takes, I would expect a mapreduce over 5 entities to take very little time.  Like... 200ms.